# Finishing a git merge

Tags: git, github, merge

[I followed this very simple guide](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches/) on how to merge two branches using git. I was going to do it from the command line, but to be safe I opted for the GUI version instead.

This process seemed simple enough: I merged my `feature-branch` into `master` and I resolved all the merge conflicts. I then made the commit.

I went back to my command line and noticed that `feature-branch` still existed, so I went to delete it:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d feature-branch
```

then, I received the following message:

```
warning: deleting branch 'feature-branch' that has been merged to

     'refs/remotes/origin/feature-branch', but not yet merged to HEAD.

Deleted branch feature-branch (was 288f261).
```

And when I go to the GitHub website, I see that the `feature-branch` has not been graphically merged into `master`.

How do I fix this problem and complete the merge?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147360/git-branch-d-gives-warning).

Comment: Well obviously you **didn't** merged it to master. Just a tiny advise here. Use the commandline because you can reproduce easier what you have done. GUIs are hiding information from you.

Answer (score 0):

This is warning you that the changes pushed to the branch origin are not merged into master so the delete occurs locally so simple use git push --delete origin  to remove it from the remote.

Comment: If this answer helped. Select it as the answer.